# How to create an hstring from C++/WinRT DateTime?

Tags: c++-winrt

I would like to know what's the simplest way to convert
`Windows::Foundation::DateTime dt = winrt::clock::now();` into an hstring?

Comment: What information should the string representation contain?

Answer (score 1):

There is no "conversion" per se. I suspect what you're looking for is some kind of date/time formatting utility.

C++20 will bring greatly improved support in this domain, but it's not here yet.

The portable, but feature-poor way to do this is to convert to time_t and use the C library. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c

The full-featured way of doing this in WinRT is to use the date formatting utilities here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.globalization.datetimeformatting

Answer (score 1):

It is not pretty, but you could do this:

```
winrt::Windows::Foundation::DateTime dt = winrt::clock::now();
std::time_t t = dt.time_since_epoch().count();

std::wstringstream wss;
wss << std::put_time(std::localtime(&t), L"%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S");
winrt::hstring hs{ wss.str() };
```